# What is minimum raise when starting a new round of betting in NLHE?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, no-limit, raise

Generally speaking what is the minimum raise amount after a new card is dealt in No-Limit Texas Hold 'em?

Examples:

**Pre-Flop.** Small Blind $1, Big Blind $2. Everybody calls.

**Post-flop.** Is the minimum raise still the big blind, $2?

*What is minimum?* Let's say during post-flop round someone then raises $10 and everybody calls.

**After the turn**, is the minimum raise now $10 or does it go back to the big blind of $2 since it's a new round?

**After the turn** someone raises $10 and then another raises $10 for total of $20.

*What is the minimum* after the river now? Is it $20 as in continuation of minimums from previous rounds of betting or something else?

I hope I'm being clear.

I read over the suggested possible duplicate "[Trying to express NL betting rules formally, did I miss anything?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/921/trying-to-express-nl-betting-rules-formally-did-i-miss-anything)" and didn't see this specific question answered there. That question does say that the minimum goes back to zero on the post flop but then mentions the minimum is max of current bet plus raise or big blind. It doesn't address subsequent rounds or specifically if prior round best affect the minimums for subsequent rounds of betting.

I realize there can be different rules and different situations and dealers and such; I'm just looking for general guideline. I'm writing a programming tutorial for internal use and using NLHE as the programming exercise so it actually isn't important if I get the rules exactly right. I'm not clear on this issue though after reading a lot rules from a lot of sources.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to express NL betting rules formally, did I miss anything?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/921/trying-to-express-nl-betting-rules-formally-did-i-miss-anything)

Comment: @HerbWolfe thank you for the reference. I added some additional comments about that related question and what is not clarified from my question by the referenced question.

Comment: Betting starts over each round with a min bet and min raise of 1 bb.

Comment: @paparazzo thank you, that is exactly what I need to know. Will you re-post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Betting starts over each round with a min bet and min raise of 1 bb.

Comment: That's not always true. There are no-limit game structures where the minimum bet is more than the big blind: e.g. "1/3 5-to-go".

Comment: Consider raising 2bb at the preflop stage: does that mean `I'll add 2bb into the pot` or does that mean `I'll add 3bb into the pot, 1bb to match the existing bb and 2bb extra`?

Answer (score 0):

Minimum raise is general "double the last bet/raise amount".

So in an unraised preflop on $1/$2, it's $4; If someone already raised to $4, then you need to raise to $6 (the last raise is $2 extra).

There are a few related rules like (live games):

- If you accidentally put in half or more of the required raise, it's a raise. So if you put in $5 accidentally trying to call a $4 raise, you are automatically raising to $6.
- You cannot reraise an all-in if the all-in is not a technical raise. So if you bet $100 into a pot and someone (villain) raise you to $200 total and another players goes all-in for $202. The villain CANNOT reraise once you flat called the $202 because the all-in guy didn't all-in enough ($202 is not more than half of a required raise).

Answer (score 0):

In no-limit play, the minimum *opening* bet for each round is the same; it does not go up on the turn like a limit game. It is usually the amount of the big blind, but sometimes more (there are 1/2 blind 4-to-go games, for example).

So it doesn't matter which betting round you are on, the first bet must be at least the minimum bet, and each raise thereafter must at least equal the previous bet. So if it's a $2 minimum game, the initial bet on every round must be at least $2. If a player opens the betting round for, say, $10, then the next raise must be at least $10.

Answer (score -1):

**Minimum raise is the smallest amount anyone on the table who has made a legit bet/raise has to call plus the amount you'd have to call plus the amount that you already put into the pot on that round.**

This is very confusing. I will give some examples.

So if someone bets $2, the smallest amount that is to be called is $2. So this amount plus the amount you'd have to call equals $4.

If someone bets $2 and another raises to $4, then the smallest amount anyone on the table has to call is $2. Plus the amount you'd have to call equals $6.

Similarly if someone bets $2, and then someone else raises to $5, the minimum raise is $8.

One last example. If you bet $2, someone raises to $4 and someone else raises to $6. Your minimum raise is $8. You already put in $2, minimum amount that is to be called is $2, your call would have been $4. That totals $8.

I hope this makes sense.