# Initial betting options on the preflop, and other streets on poker software

Tags: rules, no-limit, raise

On preflop, action starts with three options Raise 2BB, 3BB, 4BB, and when someone raises, action continues with, minimum raise, half pot raise, pot raise. on the flop action starts with a BB bet, and when someone bets, action continues with minimum raise, half pot raise, pot raise. Is this correct? Also of course one can raise any amount, but these are the options given by poker software.

I am not asking about the min-raise rule or reopening betting action. The question here is about the raise options given by the poker software as opposed to raising manually, and whether they have a formal definition or are they just arbitrary custom options. It's like 3-bet 5-bet continuation bet kind of thing.

On some other site i found there are different options:

```
initial preflop: min 3bb 5bb allin
initial bet: min 1/2 pot allin
reraise: min 2x 4x allin
sometimes: min 1/2 3/4 allin
```

So preflop an initial bet is expressed in terms of blinds, on other streets, an initial bet is expressed as pot size, a reraise is expressed as 2x 4x (two times more), and sometimes it is expressed as pot size 1/2 3/4.

My question is how are the betting button options given by poker software to the players determined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to express NL betting rules formally, did I miss anything?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/921/trying-to-express-nl-betting-rules-formally-did-i-miss-anything)

Comment: I think this is a question about bet sizing

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: do you play poker on sites, where they have buttons for how much to raise? @Jonast92

Comment: @eguneys Of course. They have default values that you can usually customize. I don't understand your question or what you're trying to get answered, or the reason for the question.

Comment: I am asking if there is a definition for different raise options these buttons are showing. I am writing poker software so I am trying to implement them. @Jonast92

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is referring to what buttons you should implement on poker software as raise/bet sizing options.

If it were me writing this software, I would copy one of your favorite sites to start and then see if there are any improvements you can make. Maybe you can make the buttons customizable, so if someone likes to raise to 2.8BB preflop they can change the button to reflect that.

I think that if you implement any of the general things that you listed above, they would be just fine. Sometimes I think the buttons change depending on stack size too, so you can do a little bit of research on that.

Comment: So anything is fine as long as it's between min raise and max raise range?

Comment: @eguneys yes, the purpose of those buttons is convenience